# Nagios mail directory is missing

Tags: email, redhat, nagios

I've implemented Nagios 3.5.1 on one node to monitor basic metrics coming from Ganglia gmetad and gmond clients to Nagios via ganglia-nagios-bridge.py script.

Currently, I'm having issues with alerts, as e-mails do not get sent out, even when I can see alerts being logged in the Nagios web UI. One suspicion I have is that there are 2 missing missing files, /var/spool/mail/nagios and /var/mail/nagios. I would like to find out why these 2 files are missing, and what I can do to work around this.

The following is my contacts.cfg file:

```
define contact{
        contact_name    nagiosadmin                                        ;     Short name of user
        use             generic-contact                                                 ; Inherit default values from generic-contact template (defined above)
        alias           Nagios Admin                                                    ; Full name of user

        email           brazelton.w.mann@hpe.com  ; <<***** CHANGE THIS TO     YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS ******
        }


###############################################################################
###############################################################################
#
# CONTACT GROUPS
#
###############################################################################
###############################################################################

# We only have one contact in this simple configuration file, so there is
# no need to create more than one contact group.

define contactgroup {
        contactgroup_name       admins
        alias                   Nagios Administrators
        members                 nagiosadmin
}
```

I've validated I can use the mail command to send e-mails to this address. Operations system: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6.

Commands run to install nagios and dependent components:

`yum install httpd`

`yum install mailx`

`yum install nagios`

`yum install nagios-www`

`yum install nagios-plugins-all`

`yum install nagios-plugins-nrpe`

`yum install php`

Answer (score 0):

First please check if you're able to send e-mail from operating system by following command:

```
echo test | mail -s 'test mail' yourmail@mailservice.com
```

If you are receiving email then probably you have problem with them mail command configuration.